# Angular 2 RC5: Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular

After upgrading to RC5, I suddenly got this error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

<div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="t of test">{{t}}</div>")
```

The HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="t of test">asdas</div>
```

All posts on this topic explain that you need to import BrowserModule, but I already did that.

Answer (score 21):

After banging my head against the wall, I found the solution:
I had forgotten the word "let" in front of my variable!

Pre RC5 this used to work, so this is a breaking change in RC5. I know let is required, but previously this just worked. And the error is not helpful at all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was getting the same error - in my case I had the `const` keyword in front of the `t`

Comment: Thank you!! just had the same, that's what happens when you gotta code in a hurry coz your bosses think you don't have your own life...
cheers mate